# Images in react not showing up

Tags: image, reactjs, path

Learning react and want to show up an image on the main page from my folder. 
I put the picture here 
`..\client\myapp\src\imagefolder\myimage.jpg`
In react's App.js I do 
`<img src='./imagefolder/myimage.jpg' alt="hel"/>
 <img src='/imagefolder/myimage.jpg' alt="hel"/>`
Both of these methods dont work.
I did that because App.js is inside src folder and I am trying to navigate from my position to the picture. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends how you are building your app - are you using webpack? Is there a public folder where you can put your images?

Comment: Yes. There is a public folder on the main root folder. Should I create a imagefolder there instead?

Comment: That would be logical :)

Comment: I did that but it says it falls outside of the src directory and is not supported. I am currently bypassing it by creating the folder inside of the src directory, importing the image on my app.js and doing `<img src={myimg} />`

Comment: I think you should find the right path of your images on network first. You are now using relative path to the image, you can see the absolute path in browser devtools